# Polygon to Lines in Virtual Layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, convert, virtual-layer

Is there a way in QGIS to transform a Polygon layer (shapefile) to a Line layer through "Virtual Layers"?
In case there is how could I in addition to making the conversion also avoid duplicate geometries in this virtual layer, so that polygons that share boundaries with each other will generate only a single line when converted to lines?

Comment: It is not straight but it is possible, check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382382 for instance, there one  step forward was done, so you need to get the interior and exterior rings (depends whether your polygons posses holes). However, I want to ask why do you want to make your life a bit more complicated when QGIS/GRASS geoalgorithms are marvelous for solving exactly your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You will get best results if you install Grass GIS together with QGIS and use the processing tool v.to.lines.

[image]