# Getting coordinate vertices of a polyline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, coordinates, vertices

How can I get the (x,y) coordinates of the vertices of a polyline in QGIS?

I do not find the function in the field-calculator

I can find the coordinates for each point, but I am not able to highlight it only for the first and the last point for each polyline.
I would like to link those value for each polyline

Comment: Convert the line to points, then use the tool `add geometry columns`.

Comment: How I can highlight the first and last points for each polyline?

Comment: `start_point($geometry)` and `end_point($geometry)`

Comment: That is a different question.

Comment: See also this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381187/convert-vertices-of-polygon-features-to-points-using-virtual-layer-in-qgis

Comment: @Babel i think your reference is too complex for this issue

Comment: @Taras that might be, just if it is for interest to the OP (not a new user)

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? Get the X and Y, get the geometry, style the line showing the start/end points, label the points, else?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use for all the items the function:

- $y_at (**0**) and $x_at (**0**) (coordinates of the **first** point of the polyline)
- $y_at (**-1**) and $x_at (**-1**) (coordinates of the **last** point of the polyline)